# Key's random art image is mostly black

Tags: passwords, ssh, random

I have generated an SSH key on Ubuntu 10.04 with

```
 ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "example@example.com"
```

and the key's random art image comes out mostly empty (modified slightly):

```
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|        D        |
|      s.J        |
|       Bv.++=    |
|      =ooo.=o+   |
|     c .+*.+o.   |
+-----------------+
```

Does that indicate an issue with the random number generator?

Comment: See also [What is randomart produced by ssh-keygen?](http://superuser.com/questions/22535/what-is-randomart-produced-by-ssh-keygen)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

The "random art" image is created by a [random walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk) through the image area, using the key's fingerprint as the sequence of moves to make.  The fingerprint is short enough that the art can never cover more than about 40% of the image.

An analysis of the art and some attempts at attacks on it are available in the paper "[The Drunken Bishop](http://www.dirk-loss.de/sshvis/drunken_bishop.pdf)".